# Constructing the 'idealized white noise' stochastic process

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

There are some authors, namely H. Holden, B. Øksendal, and J. Ubøe T. Zhang in their book *Stochastic Partial Differential Equations. A Modeling, White Noise Functional Approach*,
that define *idealized 1-dimensional white noise* as a "stochastic process" $\{\dot W_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ with the following properties:

1. It is a mean zero Gaussian process.
2. If $t_1\neq t_2$ then $\dot W_{t_1}$ and $\dot W_{t_2}$ are independent.
3. It is a stationary process.

As the commenters observed and mentioned this already, I have found that author  B. Øksendal of the book *Stochastic Differential Equations* mentions that :

> If we require that $\mathbb{E}\big[\dot W_t^2\big]=1$, then the function $(\omega,t)\mapsto \dot W_t(\omega)$ cannot even be measurable, with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}\times \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,\infty]$.

However, in several references I have read so far, I do not see an explicit construction of this process with index set $T=\mathbb{R}^+$. Rather, white noise is defined in the following two ways.

---

***White noise indexed by a $\sigma$-algebra of a $\sigma$-finite measure space.***

Let $(M,\mathcal{F},\sigma)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and let $T$ be the collection of all sets in $\mathcal{F}$ of finite measure. White noise $\{W_A\}_{A\in T}$ is then defined as mean zero Gaussian process such that the following hold.

- For each $A\in T$, $W_A$ is a normal random variable with zero mean and variance $\sigma(A)$.
- If $A, B\in T$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$ then $W_A$ and $W_B$ are independent.
- For all $A,B\in T$ we have that $W(A\cup B)=W(A)+W(B)-W(A\cap B)$.

We use some version of the Bochner-Minlos theorem to get the existence of such a process. It has the property that for any $A,B\in T$ that $\text{Cov}(W_A,W_B)=\sigma(A\cap B)$. Note that if $M=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\sigma=\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure then the process
$$\{B_t\}_{t\geq 0}:=\left\{W\left((0,t]\right)\right\}_{t\geq 0}$$ is just regular Brownian motion.

---

***White noise indexed by Shwartz functions.***

Let $T:=\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ be the Shwartz space rapidly decreasing smooth functions.
Let $\Omega:=\mathcal{S'}(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of tempered distributions equipped with the cylinder algebra $\mathscr{C}$. Another version of the Bochner-Minlos theorem states that there is a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $(\Omega,\mathscr{C})$ such that
$$\int_\Omega e^{i\langle \omega,\varphi\rangle} d\mathbb{P}(\omega)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\|\varphi\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}\right),\;\;\;\text{ for all }\varphi\in T.$$
White noise is then defined as
$$W(t,\omega):=\langle \omega, \varphi \rangle,\;\;\;\text{ for all }(t,\omega)\in T\times \Omega.  $$
Note that for $\omega\in\Omega$ and for any $\varphi\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ one can define $\langle \omega,\varphi\rangle$ by using a sequence of functions $\{\varphi_n\}$ in $T$ that converge to $\varphi$. This allows to define the following:
$$B_t(\omega):=\langle \omega,\mathbf{1}_{(0,t]}\rangle,\;\;\;\text{ for all }t\in\mathbb{R}^+. $$
Then $\{B_t\}$ is just one dimensional Brownian motion.

---

***The Question:***

As you can see, one can use white noise (defined in any of the above ways) to construct Brownian motion.

- Can we use the Shwartz space indexed or $\sigma$-algebra indexed white noise $W$, to otain the 'idealized white noise' $\{\dot W_t\}$ indexed by time?
- Is there another way to construct $\dot W$?

---

***My idea:*** (can skip this part)

We can use the second construction of white noise above to define a process called the  *smoothed white noise process*. It is defined as follows: For $\varphi\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and any $t\in \mathbb{R}$ let $$\varphi_t(x):=\varphi(t-x),\;\;\;\text{ for }x\in \mathbb{R}.$$ Then define
$$W_\varphi(t,\omega):=W(\varphi_t,\omega)=\langle \omega,\varphi_t\rangle,\;\;\;\text{ for all }(t,\omega)\in T\times\Omega. $$

$W_\varphi$ is then a zero mean stationary Gaussian process with constant variance equal to $\|\varphi\|_{L^2}$. It has the properties that for any $t_1\neq t_2$, if $\varphi_{t_1}$ and $\varphi_{t_2}$ have disjoint supports then $W(t_1,\cdot)$ and $W(t_2,\cdot)$ are independent.

So I was thinking, if we take a sequence $\{\varphi_n\}$ in $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ with shrinking supports, then would the sequence of smoothed white noises $\{W_{\varphi_n}\}$ converge (in a appropriate sense) to an idealized white noise $\dot W$?

Comment: What about $\otimes_{t \in \mathbb{R}_+} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, the product of standard normal distributions?

Comment: You mean to say that we use the Kolomogorov extension theorem?

Comment: Seems to be one of the most simple ways to construct white noise.

Comment: What you call 'idealised white noise' is not white noise. It also isn't a stochastic process in the usual sense because it cannot be made measurable in $t$.

Comment: It is an unconventional naming I agree.  I noticed it in the book Stochastic Partial Differential Equations: A Modeling, White Noise Functional Approach. I am aware that this is a generalised srochastic process. However, why is the definition of white noise if you say that the above is not white noise?

Comment: @Dieter Kadelka Note that the variance  of $\dot{W}$ is infinite....

Comment: I believe there is some confusion in this question: you confuse the generalized noise (which is only defined as a distribution) with its action on test functions. There is no way to define the white noise pointwise, as you wanted.

Comment: @UserA: "idealized white noise" in the book is to be understood as "heuristic/physicsy white noise". Moreover, they don't give the variance of $\dot{W}_t$ because this is a "$N(0,\infty)$" variable. The issue here is one should not take seriously the  $t$-indexed process $\{\dot{W}_t\}_{t\ge 0}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$

> - Can we use white noise $W$ to construct idealized white noise $\dot W$?

First, use your favorite white noise $W$ to construct a standard Brownian motion $B$, as you did in your post. Then, by the Kolmogorov extension theorem, the finite-dimensional distributions of the process $\dot W^{(\ep)}$ defined by the formula
$$\dot W^{(\ep)}_t:=\frac{B_{t+\ep}-B_t}{\sqrt\ep}\tag{1}$$
for real $t\ge0$ converge (as $\ep\downarrow0$) to the finite-dimensional distributions of what you refer to as an idealized white noise $\dot W$; here we used the fact that, for any $k$-tuple $(t_1,\dots,t_k)$ of nonnegative real numbers and all small enough $\ep>0$, the intervals $[t_1,t_1+\ep],\dots,[t_k,t_k+\ep]$ will be pairwise disjoint.

> - Is there another way to construct $\dot W$?

Yes, as suggested in comments by Dieter Kadelka, you can use the Kolmogorov extension theorem directly to construct an "idealized white noise" $\dot W$.

---

**Comments:**

1. I think the notation $\dot W$ for your "idealized white noise" is not appropriate, because the denominator in (1) is, not $\ep$, but $\sqrt\ep$.
2. It is unclear to me why you need this "idealized white noise".

Comment: The variables $\dot{W}^{(\epsilon)}_t$, for a fixed $t$, do not converge anywhere in distribution: it is a sequence of Gaussian variables whose variances blows up...

Comment: @oferzeitouni : The variance of $\dot W^{(\varepsilon)}_t$ is $1$.

Comment: Sure, I did not notice you divided by $\sqrt{\epsilon}$... Then, this object does not converge to $\dot{W}$.... what he wanted is white noise, and your scaling is inappropriate for that - if you integrate your $\dot{W}_t^{(\epsilon)}$ against a smooth test function, you will get $0$ in the limit.

Comment: @oferzeitouni : Yes, of course, because the "idealized white noise" is not an actual white noise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To answer comment 2, I do not need it for anything specific. First of all, it seemed a priori natural to have the 'continuous equivalent 'of a coin tossing process, which is how I heuristically think of white noise. Second, to clarify: I did not know that such a process (what I call idealized white noise) is not measurable w.r.t $t$ and has infinite variance (would be great if you can clarify why). So I looked at at how authors define white noise and said: "maybe I can use their definition of noise to define idealized white noise".

Comment: @UserA : The comment about the non-measurability was made by Martin Hairer, not by me. I have not seen this fact, and I have not even seen this "idealized white noise" in publications. If I had to prove the non-measurability, I guess I'd try using, first, Lusin's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem) and then maybe something like the Lebesgue's density theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem).

Comment: How about the infinite variance? What I understand so far is that $\dot W$ has infinite variance, yet we can construct it using the Kolmogorov extension theorem. Can you clarify this part? Sorry for asking too much but this is a crucial point for me.

Comment: @UserA If you want your $\dot W$ to be actual white noise (which is rigorously defined in one of the two ways you mention in your question), then this can *heuristically* be thought of as i.i.d. Gaussians with infinite variance, just like the 'delta function' can be heuristically thought of as a function that vanishes everywhere except at the origin where it is infinite. Real white noise is of course not built by Kolmogorov's extension theorem in the way suggested. (It can as a test function-indexed process though.) ...

Comment: ... On the other hand, you can use Kolmogorov's extension theorem to construct an $\mathbb{R}$-indexed i.i.d. collection of Gaussian random variables with some fixed *finite* variance (say $1$). This is what most commenters here believe you mean when you talk about 'idealised white noise' and what I mentioned cannot be realised as a jointly measurable stochastic process. The relation between the two is like the relation between the 'delta function' and the indicator function of the set $\{0\}$, i.e. intuitively appealing but actually pretty much nonexistent.

Comment: @MartinHairer : I think I have an idea how to prove the impossibility of the joint measurability. But do you know what can be said about the (lack of ?) measurability of almost all realizations of the "idealized white noise"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis What exactly would you mean by such a statement given that the set of measurable functions isn’t itself measurable with respect to the product sigma-algebra?

Comment: @MartinHairer : I guess I meant this:Do there exist a probability space and a family $X=(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ of independent standard normal variables defined on this probability space such that the inner probability of the set of all measurable realizations of $X$ is $1$?

Comment: @MartinHairer Indeed, using the Kolmogorov extension theorem to come up with a family of iid Gaussian random variables with fixed finite variance is what I seek. However, the comment (under the question) by ofer zeitouni suggested that even with this construction, the variance is infinite, which was confusing for me. So to seal the deal: $\{\dot W_t\}$ is constructed using the Kolmogorov theorem (as $\otimes_t N(0,1)$), but is not a stochastic process but rather a random field. Is that correct?

Comment: @UserA If by random field you mean any $\mathbb{R}$-indexed family of random variables then yes. Most authors would however implicitly assume some measurability with respect to the underlying space when talking about a 'random field', so I would think that in most cases it wouldn't qualify...

Comment: @MartinHairer  As you said in your comments and as mentioned in the answer, we can "**use Kolmogorov's extension theorem to construct an $\mathbb{R}$-indexed i.i.d. collection of Gaussian random variables with some fixed *finite* variance**". But I still don't understand, why did some of the commenters say that $\{\dot W_t\}$ will have **infinite** variance? (I'm referring to the comments by @oferzeitouni)

Comment: @UserA: The usual time-derivative of the Brownian motion would have infinite variance, I think this is what Ofer Zeitouni meant.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: It is not very difficult to see that a jointly measurable resalisation of such a process $(X_t)$ is not possible. With your statement (that $t \mapsto X_t$ is measurable with probability one), however, this may get difficult. See, for example, these two questions: [one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/173037/108637) and [two](https://mathoverflow.net/q/102386/108637) (especially the latter one, I think).

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki : Thank you for the references to those two questions.